# Dual y-axis plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Want to do a dual axis plot and I am stuck with some details - maybe someone can point me in the right direction? The main problem is that both bar plots overlap!

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{206,230,202}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{145,208,206}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{86,185,210}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{63,151,194}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{51,113,170}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{39,75,147}
\definecolor{color7}{RGB}{27,39,124}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar = 5pt,
    bar width=8pt,
    x=1.2cm,
    axis y line*=left,       
    ymin = 0.2,
    ymax = 1,
    axis on top,
    xtick={Default, AS, BFA, BFC, LS, BFA-LS, Robust},
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={Default, AS, BFA, BFC, LS, BFA-LS, Robust},
    %restrict y to domain*=0:1200, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
        \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
    },
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
    },
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false,
    ylabel={Dice Score},
    xlabel={Average for Method},
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    ]    
    \addplot[fill=color5] coordinates {(Default, 0.4512103812) (AS, 0.631082628) (BFA, 0.6600940641)  (BFC, 0.6531076378) (LS, 0.6362765231) (BFA-LS, 0.6547464862) (Robust, 0.69035633)};

    \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
        every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        ybar = 5pt,
        bar width=8pt,
        x=1.2cm,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 10,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        ylabel={Change in \%},
        symbolic x coords={Default, AS, BFA, BFC, LS, BFA-LS, Robust},
        visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
        nodes near coords={%
            \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
        axis y line*=right,
        axis x line=none,
        ]    
            \addplot[fill=color5] coordinates {(Default, 0.3512103812) (AS, 0.631082628) (BFA, 0.6600940641)  (BFC, 0.6531076378) (LS, 0.6362765231) (BFA-LS, 0.6547464862) (Robust, 0.69035633)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: might be, but the main problem is that the bars overlap!

Comment: add `bar shift={-\pgfplotbarwidth/2}` to the first `axis` options and `bar shift={\pgfplotbarwidth/2}` to the second `axis` options ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow, why ? In pgfplots § two ordinates p275 there is not need such shift

Comment: You can add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` in the prehambule of your document

Comment: That fixed the axis issue, but that doesn't fix the overlapping issue

Comment: @flav, is my explanation in my answer sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

To fix the `ylabel` positioning of the second `ylabel` just add `compat=1.3` or higher in the preamble (this is -- in the meantime -- also already mentioned in [a comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470356/dual-y-axis-plot#comment1184853_470356)).

The bars overlap, because you have two independent `axis` environments and thus, the two `\addplot` commands don't "know" of each other. Therefore the bars are just plotted on top of the xticks. To avoid this you have to manually shift them.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \definecolor{color5}{RGB}{51,113,170}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat` level or higher to make use of the "advanced"
        % label positioning (this brings the second ylabel to the right)
        compat=1.3,
        % (created a style for the common options)
        my axis style/.style={
            every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
            ybar=5pt,
            bar width=8pt,
            x=1.2cm,
            axis on top,
            enlarge x limits=0.1,
            symbolic x coords={Default, AS, BFA, BFC, LS, BFA-LS, Robust},
            %restrict y to domain*=0:1200, % Cut values off at 14
            visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
%            after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
%                \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
%            },
            nodes near coords={%
                \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
            xtick distance=1,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        ymin=0.2,
        ymax=1,
        axis y line*=left,
        xlabel={Average for Method},
        ylabel={Dice Score},
        % to avoid overlapping, move the "first" bars to the left ...
        bar shift={-\pgfplotbarwidth/2},
    ]
        \addplot [fill=color5] coordinates {
            (Default, 0.4512103812)
            (AS, 0.631082628)
            (BFA, 0.6600940641)
            (BFC, 0.6531076378)
            (LS, 0.6362765231)
            (BFA-LS, 0.6547464862)
            (Robust, 0.69035633)
        };
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel={Change in \%},
        % ... and the second bars to the right
        bar shift={\pgfplotbarwidth/2},
    ]
        \addplot [fill=color5] coordinates {
            (Default, 0.3512103812)
            (AS, 0.631082628)
            (BFA, 0.6600940641)
            (BFC, 0.6531076378)
            (LS, 0.6362765231)
            (BFA-LS, 0.6547464862)
            (Robust, 0.69035633)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: @Styp, does my answer solve your question(s) or do you need further assistance? In the first case, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).